# Find an equation of the tangent line at the indicated point on the graph of a function.

Tags: calculus

Struggling to understand this

1. calculus problem. Think I know where to start, but am unsure of how
   to finish it.

   $$y=F(x)=8\sqrt{x}-x+5,\\ (x,y)=(64,5)$$
2. I take the derivative of the equation $8x^{1/2}-x^{-1} +5$ Then I plug in the $x$ value (I think)? 
   $8(64^{1/2})-64+5$ simplifies to $64-64+5=5$. slope$=5$ Correct?

3.Then I put it in the slope formula? and use the given points for the second $y$ and $x$ values?
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)\\ y-5=5(x-64)$$ simplifies to $y-5=5x-320$ which simplifies to $y=5x-315$. This is not an answer option and I am unsure of the steps I used or where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 1):

To find the equation of the tangent line to the function

$$F(x) = 8\sqrt{x} - x + 5$$

at the point $(64, 5)$, we find the derivative, evaluate it when $x = 64$, then find the equation of the line through the point $(64, 5)$ whose slope is equal to $F'(64)$.

\begin{align*}
F(x) & = 8\sqrt{x} - x + 5\\
     & = 8x^{\frac{1}{2}} - x + 5
\end{align*}

Differentiating yields

\begin{align*}
F'(x) & = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 8x^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 1\\
      & = \frac{4}{\sqrt{x}} - 1
\end{align*}

Evaluating the derivative when $x = 64$ yields

\begin{align*}
F'(64) & = \frac{4}{\sqrt{64}} - 1\\
       & = \frac{4}{8} - 1\\
       & = \frac{1}{2} - 1\\
       & = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Hence, the tangent line to the graph of $F(x)$ at the point $(64, 5)$ has slope $-1/2$.  Using the point-slope equation $$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$ with $(x_0, y_0) = (64, 5)$ and $m = -1/2$ yields

$$y - 5 = -\frac{1}{2}(x - 64)$$